# OneDrive not Sync from sharepoint link from Office 365

Tags: sync, onedrive, office365

I have a user who has a company Office 365 account, and has OneDrive 2015 version 17.3 installed (this seems to be the latest version as far as I can tell) on Windows 10.

We added the Business Account to this and it syncs his personal 365 OneDrive fine.

When we open the 365 Sites/Sharepoint documents folder and click the `Sync now` link, nothing happens. Tried this on Chrome and then tried via Edge - nothing happens when the link is clicked.

When I click these links on my PC, one drive sets up a sync with the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your running the next generation client.  Things are a bit confusing at the moment as there are 3 different sync clients in the wild.

The client you are running which is the latest.  This works and can connect to both a personal OneDrive account and a business account.

The older client that came with Office is based on Groove application, and Syncs with SharePoint libraries (Including OneDrive for Business).

And then you have the original OneDrive personal client that syncs with, well OneDrive Personal.

With the Next gen client you can ONLY sync OneDrive (personal and business) not SharePoint libraries.  To continue to sync SharePoint libraries you must have the groove client.  You can download that directly from here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2903984

More information on the Next Gen client and some current limitation are available here:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-OneDrive-for-Business-Next-Generation-Sync-Client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49

That client is what Microsoft is moving towards.  They are planning on adding back the SharePoint sync into the tool so you only need one client to sync OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, and SharePoint libraries.

Comment: Many thanks, great answer. You're right it _is_ confusing - it's so hard to distinguish what client you're using. So updating in this case actually caused the problem. I'll see if I can downgrade the user's version

Comment: As a head up - there is a switch in SharePoint online that will enforce the use of the new client.  My understanding is that Microsoft is going to begin requiring it's use and rolling this setting out starting next Month.  The old client will still work with SharePoint sites, but not OneDrive for Business.